# Unable to Delete PDF File After Appending to Other PDF File - C# - ItextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, process, itext

I am trying to append  load of PDF files to one new PDF using the `iTextSharp` library, and I would like to delete the individual files (which were converted from .DOC format) after this has been done.

This is the final piece of code, which attached all the files, and this is where I believe the problem lies:

```
    static void Concat(string targetPdf, string[] newPdfFiles)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);

            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in orderedlist)
            {
                if (!(file.Contains("HR Policies and Procedures Guide")))
                {
                    var newFileName = "\\\\file\\IT\\SK\\test\\" + file.Split('.')[0] + ".pdf";
                    pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(newFileName));
                }
                i++;
            }

            pdf.Close();
            pdfDoc.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Before using `pdf.AddDocument(new PdfReader(newFileName));` , I am able to delete any of the PDF files without any issue, by using `System.IO.File.Delete("\\\\Path\\To\\File.pdf");`

However, if I try doing this after running `AddDocument`, I am seeing the following exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in     mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The process cannot access the     file '\\file\IT\SK\test\HR Policies and Procedures Acceptance Form.pdf' because it is being used by another process.
```

I have tried calling .Close() and .Dispose() on both pdf and pdfDoc variables without any success.

I have also checked which processes I am currently running with Process Explorer, but there are so many I have no idea where to start.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can overcome this?

Comment: Have you tried putting `new PdfReader(newFileName)` into a variable and passing that variable to `pdf.AddDocument` and then disposing of the variable manually after use? The error you are seeing is because the file you are reading from is still locked by the PdfReader that is accessing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Skuzzbox mentioned in the comment, the actual culprit here was `PdfReader`, which I was originally declaring at the same time as calling `pdf.AddDocument` (see question).

However, declaring this first, calling it, and then disposing of that variable alone released the pdf file from use so that I was free to delete it:

```
    static void Concat(string targetPdf, string[] newPdfFiles)
    {
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(targetPdf, FileMode.Create))
        {
            iTextSharp.text.Document pdfDoc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4);

            PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(pdfDoc, stream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            foreach (string file in orderedlist)
            {
                if (!(file.Contains("HR Policies and Procedures Guide")))
                {
                    var newFileName = "\\\\file\\IT\\SK\\test\\" + file.Split('.')[0] + ".pdf";

                    PdfReader test = new PdfReader(newFileName);
                    pdf.AddDocument(test);
                    test.Dispose();

                    // Delete the individual pdf ..
                    System.IO.File.Delete(newFileName);
                }

                pdfDoc.Close();
                pdf.Close(); 
            }
        }
    }
```

This makes sense, as that is the variable which was actually trapping the file. While the other processes which I was trying to Dispose of / Close were manipulating the files, the PdfReader variable is representing the actual pdf file.

**Edit** Added `pdf.Close();` and `pdfDoc.Close();` as without these the pdf final file was corrupted

Comment: One other options is if you have small-ish PDFs, maybe a couple of MBs or less, you can just use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)` and pass that directly into the `new PdfReader()`. The reader will then have no connection to the file and you can delete it immediately.